# input text into a comment textarea html/jquery on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, textarea

So Basically I want to make my function on Click submit the select box values to a comment box on a page this just holds it in a textarea that must be copied and pasted to the comment box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myDiv').click(function(){
    ('#select select').appendTo('myDiv');
    ('#select').css('display','block');
    ('#select select').attr('selected').html().clone().sppendTo('textarea');
});
("#ABCA").click(function(){
    var text1 = $('#equipment option:selected').val();
    var text2 = $('#locid option:selected').val();
    var text3 = $('#areaid option:selected').val();
    var text4 = $('#status option:selected').val();
    var text5 = $('#employee option:selected').val();
    var text6 = $('#Room option:selected').val();
    ('#myDiv textarea').html("The " + text1 + " is " + text4+" at " + text2+" on the/in " + text3  + text6 +" Submitted BY:  " + text5 + " Any Additional     Comments or concerns may be posted here:  ");
});
</script>
```

This is the html code of the Comment textarea i want to insert into.

```
<textarea class="input-full" name="commentText" maxlength="40000"         placeholder="Leave a comment…">Text Goes Here</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `.val()` jquery method. More specifically, [this](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value). GL

Comment: I have already tried to use this as this is what i used to get my options values. I guess my question is  more related as to how to access the comment box text area as to posting the value the above will work fine i just cant seem to access the text area from the html